# Migration from sqlite to room database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

If we move from SQLite to Room database, will the database remain intact.
Will all the entries in database remain intact.
Schema remain same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you do everything correctly.
Please refer to: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/sqlite-room-migration

Answer (score 0):

All the data can be preserved. However, the actual schema will likely have to be changed as Room has limitations on column types.

Room only accepts column types that are specifically **INTEGER**, **REAL**, **TEXT** or **BLOB**.

However, SQLite has flexible column types and uses a [simple set of rules](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity) to assign a type affinity.

- e.g. `CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn CHAR(10)....)`, even though the type affinity, according to the rules, is **TEXT**, Room will not accept **CHAR(10)**. So the schema would have to be changed and the migration of the database would have to reflect this.

Room also expects some constraints especially NOT NULL to be exact. The NOT NULL constraint in room is often implied e.g. in Java a primitive will be NOT NULL implicitly on Kotlin, which has no primitives, always objects, takes whether or not the type can be null i.e. a **`?`** that specifies nullability.

It can be a nightmare to ascertain exactly what Room expects. However, it need not be as Room can assist.

After

- a) creating the proposed `@Entity` (a table) annotated classes, and
- b) defining the `@Entity` annotated classes in the `entities` parameter of the `@Database` annotation, and
- c) then successfully compiling the project (CTRL + F9)

then Room processing will have generated some Java code (even if using Kotlin). This will be located in the java(generated) folder/directory (easily viewable from the Android View). In the generated java class, that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **_Impl**, there will be a method name **`createAllTables`**. This is the SQL according to Room's expectations and can be used for the conversion of the database from the old schema to the new schema.

---

**Demo**

---

Consider the following App (pre Room conversion) :-

The **DBHelper** class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper:-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public static final String USER_TABLE_NAME = "_user";
   public static final String NOTE_TABLE_NAME = "_note";
   public static final String USER_ID_COL = "_user_id";
   public static final String USER_NAME_COL = "_name";
   public static final String USER_EMAIL_COL = "_email";
   public static final String USER_PASSWORD_COL = "_password";
   public static final String USER_TABLE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + USER_TABLE_NAME +
           "(" +
           USER_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
           "," + USER_NAME_COL + " CHAR(64)" +
           "," + USER_EMAIL_COL + " EMAIL " +
           "," + USER_PASSWORD_COL + " PASSWORDTYPE " +
           ");";
   /* Note purposely using column types that will have to be converted for Room. */
   public static final String NOTE_ID_COL = "_note_id";
   public static final String NOTE_COL_TIMESTAMP = "_timestamp";
   public static final String NOTE_COL_TEXT = "_text";
   public static final String NOTE_COL_USER_REF = "_user_id_reference";
   public static final String NOTE_TABLE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NOTE_TABLE_NAME +
           "(" +
           NOTE_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " +
           "," + NOTE_COL_TIMESTAMP + " MyTimeStampType" +
           "," + NOTE_COL_TEXT + " MEMO " +
           "," + NOTE_COL_USER_REF + " REFERENCE_PARENT REFERENCES " + USER_TABLE_NAME +"(" + USER_ID_COL + ")" +
           ");";

   DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(USER_TABLE_CREATE_SQL);
      db.execSQL(NOTE_TABLE_CREATE_SQL);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {}

   public long insertUser(Long id, String name, String email, String password) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      if (id != null) {
         cv.put(USER_ID_COL,id);
      }
      cv.put(USER_NAME_COL,name);
      cv.put(USER_EMAIL_COL,email);
      cv.put(USER_PASSWORD_COL,password);
      return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(USER_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
   }
   public long insertUser(String name, String email, String password) {
      return insertUser(null,name,email,password);
   }

   public long insertNote(Long id, String text, long userId) {
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      if (id != null) {
         cv.put(NOTE_ID_COL,id);
      }
      cv.put(NOTE_COL_TIMESTAMP,System.currentTimeMillis());
      cv.put(NOTE_COL_TEXT,text);
      cv.put(NOTE_COL_USER_REF,userId);
      return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(NOTE_TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
   }
   public long insertNote(String text, long userId) {
      return insertNote(null,text,userId);
   }

}
```

and to use the above **MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        addSomeData();
    }

    void addSomeData() {
        long fredid = dbHelper.insertUser("Fred","fred@email.com","fred12345678");
        if (fredid > 0) {
            dbHelper.insertNote("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", fredid);
            dbHelper.insertNote("consectetur adipiscing elit", fredid);
            dbHelper.insertNote("sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", fredid);
        }
        long maryid = dbHelper.insertUser(100L,"Mary","mary@coldmail.moc","mary87654321");
        if (maryid > 0) {
            dbHelper.insertNote("Ut enim ad minim veniam", maryid);
            dbHelper.insertNote("quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", maryid);
            dbHelper.insertNote("Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.", maryid);
            dbHelper.insertNote(999L,"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", maryid);
        }
    }
}
```

And using App Inspection shows:-

[image]

and :-

[image]

and, using a query:-

[image]

So the App has obviously worked and loaded data. You can also see that SQLite's Type Affinity has been at play. That is the column types, according to App inspection, for the columns that had acceptable but non-standard types have been determined accordingly. You can also see that the pre-determined values are in the schema (e.g. MyTimeStampType is that not NUMERIC in sqlite_master).

**The Conversion**

The first step is to code the database components according to Room.

An `@Entity` class for the **User** table:-

```
@Entity(tableName = DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME)
class User {
    @PrimaryKey /* MUST ALWAYS HAVE A PRIMARY KEY */
    @ColumnInfo( name = DBHelper.USER_ID_COL) /* Optional */
    Long userId=null;
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.USER_NAME_COL)
    String userName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.USER_EMAIL_COL)
    String userEmail;
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.USER_PASSWORD_COL)
    String userPassword;
}
```

- table name and column names used from the original but not required (via `@Entity`  and `@ColumnInfo` annotation respectively).

An `@Entity` annotated class for the **Note** table (including the Foreign Key):-

```
@Entity(
        tableName = DBHelper.NOTE_TABLE_NAME,
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = User.class,
                        parentColumns = {DBHelper.USER_ID_COL},
                        childColumns = {DBHelper.NOTE_COL_USER_REF}
                )
        }
)
class Note {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.NOTE_ID_COL)
    Long noteId=null;
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.NOTE_COL_TIMESTAMP)
    long noteTimestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.NOTE_COL_TEXT)
    String noteText;
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.NOTE_COL_USER_REF)
    long noteUserRef;
}
```

The `@Database` annotated abstract class (basic to enable compilation and generation of the generated java):-

```
@Database(entities = {User.class,Note.class}, exportSchema = false, version = DBHelper.DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
}
```

Compile (Ctrl + F9) and:-

[image]

The SQL for that User and Note tables is what Room expects to find.

As the original had methods for inserting rows into each table then the equivalents has to also be coded. So an `@Dao` annotated interface or interfaces (all in one for brevity):-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long insertUser(User user);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long insertNote(Note note);
}
```

To enable use of the interface then an amendment to the `@Database` annotated class. For the demo to actually demonstrate then a singleton will be used so a method for getting the single instance. So:-

```
@Database(entities = {User.class,Note.class}, exportSchema = false, version = DBHelper.DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDAOs getAllDAOs();

    private static TheDatabase instance;
    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* For brevity of the demo */
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now if compiled (will check the DAO methods), the it compiles BUT there is a warning:-

```
warning: _user_id_reference column references a foreign key but it is not part of an index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this column. - a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom.Note
```

So a little change to the Note class

```
@ColumnInfo(name = DBHelper.NOTE_COL_USER_REF, index = true)
long noteUserRef;
```

- **Note** it is suggested that any change is followed by a compile and that the build log is checked. This can simplify ascertaining what the cause of an issue is.

It is highly likely, due to the relationship between User and Note that access to a User with it's Notes would be required. So to be able to extract such an object then a class (NOT annotated with `@Entity` i.e. a POJO).

To also demonstrate a few other extracts a few other methods. One to get a List of all Users. Another to get a single User according to the user's id.

So AllDAOs becomes:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long insertUser(User user);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long insertNote(Note note);

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME)
    List<UserWithNotes> getAllUsersWithNotes();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME)
    List<User> getAllUsers();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBHelper.USER_ID_COL + "=:userId")
    User getUserByUserId(long userId);

}
```

- **AND** the compile is successful with no warnings.
- Note the `@Transaction` this is as Room will build java that retrieves all of the children when using `@Relation`.

At this stage the conversion/migration can be considered.

The assumption is that this is an App that has been distributed and has been in use and that the App user's data needs to be retained and is unique to each user. The assumption is that the database version in the App is 1 (if not then respective increases need to be made).

The conversion will be initiated by an attempt to access the database (NOT when an instance of the **TheDatabase** class is obtained). i.e. the database will be under Room's control (there are alternatives such as perform the migration prior to Room getting control).

To use/demonstrate **MainActivity** will be changed to utilise Room. So:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //DBHelper dbHelper;
    TheDatabase db;
    AllDAOs dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        //addSomeData();

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDAOs();
        /* NOTE Database has not yet been accessed */
        for (UserWithNotes uwn: dao.getAllUsersWithNotes()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Note n: uwn.notes) {
                sb.append("\n\tNote TS=" + n.noteTimestamp + " Text is " + n.noteText);
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","User is " + uwn.user.userName + " email  is " + uwn.user.userEmail + ". There are " + uwn.notes.size() + " notes. They are");
        }
    }
}
```

Now if an attempt is made to run the activity (***DO NOT DO THIS**) then it will fail with:-

```
2023-02-18 09:38:12.741 24921-24921/a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom, PID: 24921
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom/a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: _user(a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom.User).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='_user', columns={_user_id=Column{name='_user_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, _email=Column{name='_email', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, _name=Column{name='_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, _password=Column{name='_password', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='_user', columns={_user_id=Column{name='_user_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, _name=Column{name='_name', type='CHAR(64)', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, _email=Column{name='_email', type='EMAIL', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, _password=Column{name='_password', type='PASSWORDTYPE', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

What can be ascertained is that the Room has found the database but that it is not what was expected. However, there is no indication that a migration is expected.

So `public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` could be used.

Now if run (**DO NOT DO THIS**), then the failure is:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 1 to 2 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
```

i.e. Room has yet again found the database, but sees that it was at version 1 but should be version 2 and to use a Migration.

So a Migration can be added to basically alter the tables accordingly. However, as said earlier, deciphering what needs to be changed (as per the first failure) is not the easiest of tasks. Hence, to make life easy, use of the SQL from the generated java.

So the **TheDatabase** class can now be:-

```
@Database(entities = {User.class,Note.class}, exportSchema = false, version = DBHelper.DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDAOs getAllDAOs();

    private static TheDatabase instance;
    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* For brevity of the demo */
                    .addMigrations(migratedFromVersion1toVersion2)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    static Migration migratedFromVersion1toVersion2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public  void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            String originalSuffix = "_original";
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME + " RENAME TO " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME+originalSuffix);
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DBHelper.NOTE_TABLE_NAME + " RENAME TO " + DBHelper.NOTE_TABLE_NAME+originalSuffix);
            /* SQL below copied from the generated java */
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_user` (`_user_id` INTEGER, `_name` TEXT, `_email` TEXT, `_password` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`_user_id`))");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_note` (`_note_id` INTEGER, `_timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `_text` TEXT, `_user_id_reference` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`_note_id`), FOREIGN KEY(`_user_id_reference`) REFERENCES `_user`(`_user_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION )");


            /* Now to get the original data */
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME + " SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME+originalSuffix);
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBHelper.NOTE_TABLE_NAME + " SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.NOTE_TABLE_NAME+originalSuffix);

            /* Create the additional Index (done after the inserts as more efficient) */
            db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index__note__user_id_reference` ON `_note` (`_user_id_reference`)");

            /* Cleanup */
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBHelper.NOTE_TABLE_NAME+originalSuffix);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBHelper.USER_TABLE_NAME+originalSuffix);
        }
    };
}
```

And when run the log includes:-

```
2023-02-18 10:17:20.003 26161-26161/a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom D/DBINFO: User is Fred email  is fred@email.com. There are 3 notes. They are
        Note TS=1676667551898 Text is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        Note TS=1676667551898 Text is consectetur adipiscing elit
        Note TS=1676667551899 Text is sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
2023-02-18 10:17:20.004 26161-26161/a.a.so75484142javaconverttoroom D/DBINFO: User is Mary email  is mary@coldmail.moc. There are 4 notes. They are
        Note TS=1676667551900 Text is Ut enim ad minim veniam
        Note TS=1676667551900 Text is quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Note TS=1676667551901 Text is Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        Note TS=1676667551901 Text is Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

- **i.e. the database is obviously now usable(converted) to Room and retains the original data**